# Cannot take puppy out during daily 2-hour rain shower

Tags: toilet-training, puppy

My German shepherd puppy needs to go out at 3 or 4 pm every day. Where I live during the wet season it rains heavily from 3 to 5 pm *every single day.* I'm not sure what to do because I'm having to let her poop and pee inside and I worry that is setting her back on potty training.

I cannot use potty pads because she eats them.

Comment: If the pup's gotta go she's gotta go. What's the issues with her getting wet? You can dry her off later.

Comment: There are also rain coats available for dogs, if you are concerned to take the water inside... Dogs are robust and live outside in snow and rain in some areas, so it is a good experience for the puppy. If you dry it afterwards in a place above ~15°C then there is no reason the puppy would get issues from the trip

Comment: How cold/warm is the rain? This may be an important part of the answer, if the situation could do harm your dog or not... For example cold rain is more risky than warm, and high temperatures with high humidity are more risky than with low humidity

Comment: Another thing to consider is that you want to socialize your puppy to the rain. There may come a time when there isn't a choice about them going out in the rain, and you don't want them afraid of it (or people with umbrellas, splashes from cars, etc).

Comment: Meh, its the dry season now. lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really see no other solution than to go with her either before the rain starts or worst case during the rain. As you mention, the current situation is actively reverting her potty training because every day she learns a little bit more that pooping inside is ok.

So if she usually needs to go between 3 and 4 PM and it rains between 3 and 5 PM, then you need to go with her at 2:30 PM. It's easier to change her habit to a time when she doesn't have to go urgently than to have her hold back an hour longer.

Walking usually animates dogs to pee, especially at places where other dogs peed before. Some dogs are also animated to poop by physical activity, others by being in places where other dogs pooped before.

Comment: And a second time after the rain would probably help too.